# Adding a div that slides left and right when user scrolls

Tags: javascript, css, animation, css-selectors, transform

I am trying to recreate the effect seen on [this website](https://www.su.org/executive-program?adgroupid=122958701475&utm_campaign=13060168056&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_content=520862056461&utm_term=singularity%20university&hsa_acc=5923622692&hsa_cam=13060168056&hsa_grp=122958701475&hsa_ad=520862056461&hsa_src=g&hsa_tgt=kwd-324955049911&hsa_kw=singularity%20university&hsa_mt=e&hsa_net=adwords&hsa_ver=3&gad_source=1&gclid=Cj0KCQiAzoeuBhDqARIsAMdH14FP-jrr3dOa9D2D8EPMrsupSfPvlD8MragxqUrWAAP4WaMXctaMCvYaAqqMEALw_wcB#), and pictured, specifically to a Wordpress site. Basically there are two horizontal divs, each containing a row of different words, which move in opposite directions as you scroll up and down the page.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKMnO.png)

I have it looking as I want, but don't know what javascript or other code I need to include alongside the html and css to make it move.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Best,

P.s I tried copy/pasting the .js file which I think controls the behaviour to my site, but it contains pretty much all the code for the site, and isn't doing the job!

Comment: You can try using GSAP's scrolltTrigger, Check example [here](https://gsap.com/community/forums/topic/24705-marquee-text-slider-with-scrolltrigger/)